# Why is BitDefender flagging Magento 1 sites as containing malware

Tags: magento-1.9, security, antivirus

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so apologies in advance.

I've just noticed that several Magento 1 sites I look after including development sites are now being blocked by Bitdefender as containing malware, but I've scanned them and I am absolutely sure they haven't been compromised. I notice the Porto Magento Demo theme site is also being blocked so I think it's a problem with Bitdefender.

Anyone know if there is a work around for this. I've filed false positive reports with Bitdefender but have not heard back.

A couple of customers using Bitdefender are saying that they get a malware message about JS:Trojan.Cryxos.3663

It appears that it is only the product pages that get blocked

Answer (score 0):

We had the same Failure - it is a false positive message from Bitdefender.

We checked the Website with different online tools:

https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/411df8b42fd975dfae85a1c5945bb51bb439931831e3c532bbe93861ff43c0db/detection

The information about the Trojan you get here:
https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/16968-cryxos-trojan

it looks like a false positiv message - we reported it to bitdefender.

Comment: It's really helpful to know that others noticed the same thing. Thanks for your comment. I submitted false positive reports on Friday last week but have not yet had chance to see if the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that BitDefender have now fixed the issue in their latest update